# SQL Server 2005 Percent Log Used Alert fires too fast?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transaction-log

I have a SQL Server 2005 database thats roughly half a terabyte.  Third party software that I don't control writes to the database.

I have a Maintenance Plan which backs up the transaction log, and is called by an Agent Job which executes every 3 hours. The Agent job as a second step also compresses the finished trans log backup with gzip.  Sometimes there are sporadic large bursts of updates to the database, and the transaction log starts to fill prematurely.

I created an Alert on the database based on the *SQLServer.databases* object, *Percent Log Used* counter, that responds by executing my backup trans log Agent job when percent of log used goes above 75%.

When I enabled the alert and a burst of updates occurred, the Alert fired much more quickly than the job could backup and compress the trans log, about 1 alert every 3 seconds I think.  I think a bunch of job start/exec commands were queued up, and weird things began to happen with the job - it would sit there spinning and never finish.  Job Activity Monitor said the gzip of a trans log was happening, but NO files were being compressed..
I finally had to stop the job and restart Agent.

So it looks like the Alert fires too quickly for the job.  What can I do about this?  Can I somehow set some flag (maybe a file?) while the job is working, and the alert does not call the job when the flag is set?

Am I just missing something in how this should work?

Any help appreciated.
aj

Comment: (While this has nothing to do with your question...) You probably need to backup your transaction log more often than every 3 hours. What's the acceptable amount of data loss in the event of a system failure? If you've got a database which is 500 Gigs in size I'm guessing that it's pretty important to the business and probably can't afford to loose 3 hours worth of data.

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of the Alert you can set a "Delay between responses". You can set the delay to slightly longer than it takes to do the compression.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that in the Alerts dialog.  Thanks  ;-)